# Is this a UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight bug?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition, uiviewanimation

I've got the following problem:

I've a nice working flip animation, but when I've rotate my device before animation:

1. The flip is going by the horizontal axis (rather than vertical as it should)
2. My `controller.view` (I use `controller.view`) has the previous orientation.

Where am I wrong?

thanks